# Regular Expression (php) to match a property in within a CSS rule

Tags: php, regex

I want to **write** a regular expression to match (Please note that I'm not concerned with the php functions and usage, my concern is regexp and I have given the clue of php to clarify the usage):

to match a rule if it contains the property "height" in it. What I have primarily written:

```
^.nav+(.*)+({)+(.*)
```

But I do not what should I write after that...
And here is our subject:

```
.nav,[role~=navigation]{
    clear:both;
    background:lightgrey;
    color:#5a5a5a;
    border:1px solid #c6c6c6;
    -o-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px
}

.nav:after,[role~=navigation]:after{
    content:" ";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    font-size:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden
}

.nav a,.nav a:visited,.nav button{
    background:lightgrey;
    color:#5a5a5a;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:.25em 1em;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:1.5;
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid #c6c6c6;
    -o-border-radius:0;
    border-radius:0
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

`^\.nav.*?\{[^}]+(?<=[\s;])height\s*:[^}]+\}`

Matches a whole `.nav` css rule block. (The `^\.nav.*?\{[^}]\}` part) Inside of it we add a `height:` with a look-behind to assert that the previous character is either a `;` or a whitespace. Then we need to gobble up the rest of the characters to match the whole block.

If all you want to do is **find** the rule blocks that have `height` in them, not match the whole block, then the following is sufficient:

`^\.nav.*?\{[^}]+(?<=[\s;])height\s*:`

Note that `.` has special meaning in regex, so matching `.nav` matches `nav` preceeded by any character, to match a full stop character we need to escape it: `\.`

Comment: Just a question, don't you need to write `height\s+:` instead of `height:`? I have never tried, but I think it should be possible to write whitespace there.

Comment: I think it's better to use literal character for space for its readability

Comment: I think you are right in that you could have spaces there. `+` means 1 or more however, so `\s+` would **require** a space there. `\s*` however would gobble up any whitespaces (although it might match newlines as well depending on the regex settings/flavor). I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not tested, but probably you can see the idea from this draft:

```
.nav.*?{([^}]*;|\s*)height
```

Here we check, if `height` keyword is found after `{` or a `;` (so it is a property name).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.nav.*{.*(\bheight\s*:.*;).*}
```